# Cleared wp-cache and file is still not updated

Tags: cache, wp-config, plugin-wp-supercache

I did all the following:

- Deleted the cache in the WP Super Cache settings
- Added `define('DISABLE_CACHE', true);` in my wp-config.php
- Deleted my 'cache' folder under 'wp-content'

However a theme php file is still not updating. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your FTP folder settings can be set to read only, make sure you got write permission as well, if not, chmod it to 777.

Comment: Thanks. The permissions are correct. I've been able to change the same file earlier today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem was. Everything was working correctly, but I was uploading the wrong version of the php file in question.

User error, indeed, but in the process I learned a lot about the WP cache.